# How i can get a string with a bundle and put this string into a ListView using an adapter?

Tags: listview, text, bundle, adapter, extras

Sorry for my english, my question is this: 
The class adapter for the listview wont let me use a bundle to get extras and use thIS extras(Strings) in this line code .setText(getString("...."));.

Example:

I want use this to set the text in the adapter:

Bundle carrera = getIntent().getExtras();
text01.setText(carrera.getString("key"));

Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [BundleJam](https://github.com/qazimusab/BundleJam) library can help you out. It allows you to pass information between activities and fragments at runtime, without needing to bundle information.